# EEG data classification using DNN in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Following the iris classification demo:
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tflearn#construct_a_deep_neural_network_classifier
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/monitors

I was expecting to get the same good accuracy using eeg data as input data for classification of actions. However,the accuracy obtained is below 70% using the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import shutil

IRIS_TRAINING = "eeg_training2.csv"
IRIS_TEST ="eeg_test.csv"

# Define the training inputs
def get_train_inputs():
    x = tf.constant(training_set.data)
    y = tf.constant(training_set.target)

    return x, y
# Define the test inputs
def get_test_inputs():
  x = tf.constant(test_set.data)
  y = tf.constant(test_set.target)

  return x, y


  # Needed to make sure the logging output is visible.
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

shutil.rmtree('./tmp',ignore_errors=True)

# Load datasets
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TRAINING, target_dtype=np.int, features_dtype=np.float32)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(
    filename=IRIS_TEST, target_dtype=np.int, features_dtype=np.float32)
print('Training set lenght:' + str(len(training_set)))
print('Testing set lenght:' + str(len(test_set)))
print('database loaded')


validation_metrics = {
    "accuracy":
        tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
    "precision":
        tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_precision,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES),
    "recall":
        tf.contrib.learn.MetricSpec(
            metric_fn=tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_recall,
            prediction_key=tf.contrib.learn.PredictionKey.CLASSES)
}

validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
    test_set.data,
    test_set.target,
    every_n_steps=50,
    metrics=validation_metrics,
    early_stopping_metric="loss",
    early_stopping_metric_minimize=True,
    early_stopping_rounds=200)

# Define the features used in the DNN model: 14 features with real value
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=14)]

# Build 3 layer DNN with 25, 50, 25 units respectively.
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[25, 50, 25],
                                            n_classes=2,
                                            model_dir="./tmp/eeg-model",
                                            #dropout=0.1,
                                            config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(save_checkpoints_secs=10))

# Fit model.
#classifier.fit(input_fn=get_train_inputs, steps=2000)
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
               y=training_set.target,
               steps=5000,
               monitors=[validation_monitor])

  # Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(input_fn=get_test_inputs,
                                       steps=1)["accuracy"]

print("\nTest Accuracy: {0:f}".format(accuracy_score*100) + '%\n')

  # Classify two new flower samples. first: 0 second: 1
def new_samples():
    return np.array(
      [[4289.23,4006.15,4264.62,4121.03,4327.18,4614.87,4067.69,4614.87,4196.92,4225.64,4192.31,4269.23,4595.9,4350.77],
[4291.79,4009.23,4265.64,4125.13,4330.26,4621.03,4071.79,4619.49,4193.33,4229.74,4195.38,4273.85,4601.03,4349.23],
[4293.85,4008.72,4264.62,4126.67,4333.33,4623.08,4075.9,4617.95,4193.85,4233.85,4202.05,4275.38,4607.18,4355.9],
[4295.38,4010.77,4266.67,4126.67,4333.33,4618.97,4075.9,4610.26,4193.85,4234.36,4205.13,4274.87,4605.64,4361.03],
[4294.36,4016.92,4273.33,4132.82,4335.9,4618.46,4077.95,4610.26,4196.92,4232.31,4205.64,4279.49,4609.23,4358.46],
[4289.74,4012.82,4273.33,4130.77,4333.85,4617.95,4081.03,4613.85,4195.9,4223.59,4202.05,4282.05,4609.23,4352.31],
[4286.15,4000,4265.13,4121.03,4325.64,4615.38,4078.97,4612.31,4193.85,4220.51,4194.87,4275.9,4598.97,4347.18],
[4286.15,3995.38,4263.59,4121.03,4328.21,4617.44,4074.87,4611.79,4200.51,4222.56,4191.28,4271.28,4594.36,4348.21],
[4287.18,3996.41,4271.79,4123.59,4333.33,4618.97,4074.36,4614.87,4205.13,4226.15,4194.36,4271.79,4596.41,4350.77],
[4286.67,3994.87,4273.85,4121.54,4330.77,4616.41,4075.9,4620.51,4203.08,4230.77,4197.44,4271.79,4598.46,4350.77],
[4308.21,3993.33,4260.51,4096.92,4328.72,4607.69,4060.51,4612.31,4202.56,4228.21,4191.79,4271.28,4606.67,4365.64],
[4296.92,3986.15,4249.23,4092.82,4327.69,4609.74,4064.62,4613.33,4206.67,4229.23,4192.31,4265.13,4596.41,4357.95],
[4294.36,3985.64,4245.13,4092.82,4327.69,4616.92,4066.15,4620.51,4210.77,4229.74,4196.41,4264.62,4596.41,4355.38],
[4295.38,3990.26,4247.69,4095.9,4328.21,4614.36,4059.49,4617.44,4204.1,4229.23,4197.44,4265.64,4604.1,4360],
[4300,3992.82,4254.87,4103.59,4329.74,4611.28,4056.92,4612.31,4205.13,4230.26,4198.46,4265.64,4603.08,4365.13],
[4306.67,3994.36,4263.08,4107.18,4331.28,4614.36,4061.03,4614.87,4214.87,4232.82,4203.08,4268.72,4602.05,4366.67],
[4311.79,4000,4266.67,4108.72,4334.36,4613.85,4063.08,4615.38,4213.85,4234.36,4208.21,4276.41,4610.26,4373.85],
[4313.33,4006.67,4265.64,4116.41,4335.9,4609.74,4060.51,4612.82,4205.64,4235.9,4212.31,4282.56,4617.95,4380.51],
[4314.36,4008.21,4265.64,4118.97,4336.41,4611.79,4061.03,4616.92,4212.82,4242.05,4217.95,4284.62,4619.49,4378.97],
[4317.95,4008.21,4266.15,4114.87,4337.44,4620,4066.67,4622.05,4220.51,4247.69,4218.97,4286.67,4620,4378.97]], dtype=np.float32)

predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=new_samples))

print("New Samples, Class Predictions:    {}\n".format(predictions))#Ground truth: {1,2}
```

Does someone tried Tensorflow's DNN for eeg classification? I saw a post here at stackoverflow but they used cnn which could not be the best choice for classification of eeg data. My data came from UCI's repository: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/EEG+Eye+State# . I used the first 6000 instances for training and the last 1000 for testing but results are really poor. I changed the structure of the hidden layers and increased the number of runs but results still are bad. Any suggestion about the code in order to get higher accuracy will be appreciate. Any suggestions about better approaches in Tensorflow for eeg data classification will be appreciate too.

Comment: Hi Pablo, 
Were you able to make this work? I'm working on something similar and I've just been going through the same TF Iris demo. What features/labels were you using?
Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: No really. I just wast testing and never got any improvement. I remember that there was a post where someone said he will publish a paper where he will explain how to do this properly. I guess there are already a few papers published. Good luck.